# Why got NaN column if have string column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

code

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("API.json", scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

wsMap = gc.open("Data").worksheet('Test')
dfMap = get_as_dataframe(wsMap)

def check():
    for i, row in dfMap.iterrows():
        row['price'] = i
        print(row['price'])
        if i == 5:
            print(dfMap)
            dfMapp = dfMap.loc[:, ~dfMap.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]  
            set_with_dataframe(gc.open("Data").worksheet('Test'), dfMapp) 
            return

check()
```

if i set  **Stat column** emtry
it is work **price column** can output value

https://i.stack.imgur.com/owud3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR8tK.png

output

```
0.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
     Number  price  Stat  ... 
0     0.190    0.0   NaN  ...  
1     0.195    1.0   NaN  ...  
2     0.200    2.0   NaN  ...   
3     0.205    3.0   NaN  ...  
4     0.210    4.0   NaN  ...
```

or if **Stat column** is int,float value  **price column**  it still can output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jt5w.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHlch.png

output

```
0.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
     Number  price  Stat  ... 
0     0.190    0.0   9.0  ...        
1     0.195    1.0   9.0  ...        
2     0.200    2.0   9.0  ...         
3     0.205    3.0   9.0  ...     
4     0.210    4.0   9.0  ...
```

but if i set **Stat column** have srting value 'buy' or Mix between numbers and letters  like 'x1'
**price column**  can't output value by it return NaN

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwwGi.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9xRO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUGoR.png

output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
     Number  price Stat  ...
0     0.190    NaN  buy  ...  
1     0.195    NaN  buy  ... 
2     0.200    NaN  buy  ... 
3     0.205    NaN  buy  ...  
4     0.210    NaN  buy  ...
```

output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
     Number  price Stat  ...  
0     0.190    NaN  xi1  ...          
1     0.195    NaN  gc7  ...  
2     0.200    NaN  ys0  ...       
3     0.205    NaN    9  ...  
4     0.210    NaN    9  ...
```

How fix this bug ? i want **price column** output 0 2 3 4 if **Stat column** is string value

Answer (score 1):

Your question is long,  but point I believe is straight forward.  After creating data frame

1. remove columns named *Unnamed*.  Have used a list comprehension for this
2. remove rows that are not relevant (`dropna(how="all")`)

Now whatever I randomly place in *Stat* , *Price* remains as *float64*.  It's all your over complicated cleanup code to get to active data in sheet.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
from pathlib import Path
import random

# different oauth setup
f = Path("~/.credentials//sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json").expanduser()
gc = gspread.authorize(Storage(str(f)).get())

# open google sheet and read as data frame
df = get_as_dataframe(gc.open("Data").worksheet("Test"))

# cleanup the dataframe,  remove columns that don't have names and rows that are full of NaNs
df = df.drop(columns=[c for c in df.columns if "Unnamed" in c]).dropna(how="all")

# set Stat to string values...
df = df.assign(Stat=[["buy","sell",1,np.nan][random.randint(0,3)] for x in df["Stat"].values])

print(f"{df.dtypes}\n\n{df.to_string(index=False)}")
```

**output**

```
Number    float64
Price     float64
Stat       object
dtype: object

 Number  Price  Stat
  0.190    0.0     1
  0.195    1.0  sell
  0.200    2.0  sell
  0.205    3.0  sell
  0.210    4.0     1
  0.215    5.0     1
```